# How to minimize $x+4+\frac{1}{2x-1}$?

Tags: optimization, contest-math

How can I minimize $x+4+\frac{1}{2x-1}$ for $x > \frac{1}{2}$? I have tried using AM-GM to get the inequality

$2\sqrt{\frac{x+4}{2x-1}} \leq x+4+\frac{1}{2x-1}$.

Then, using that AM = GM when the terms are equal, I got that $x = \frac{-7+\sqrt{89}}{4}$. However, when I used calculus, I got that the minimum had to be at $\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

I'm not sure where I went wrong. Can someone explain how to solve this without calculus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:   write it as $\;\dfrac{9}{2}+ \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2x-1}\,$, first, *then* think AM-GM.

Comment: Hmm but I think the OP has a good point, why doesn't AM-GM work right away?

Comment: @Ovi The OP obtained a lower bound, but not the *best* lower bound.

Comment: But when you have a $\ge$ and you can show $=$ is achieved, shouldn't that be the absolute minimum?

Comment: Hmm right I think I see the problem

Comment: @Ovi OP's lower bound depends on $x$.

Comment: @dxiv So how come your hint gives the best lower bound ?

Comment: @DarkKnight My hint shows that the expression is $\,\ge \dfrac{9}{2} + 2 \sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \cdot \dfrac{1}{2x-1}} = \dfrac{9}{2} + \dfrac{1 }{ \sqrt{2}}\,$, and that equality is attained for $\,x-\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2x-1} \iff x = \dfrac{1+ \sqrt{2}}{2}\,$. In other words, the value is a lower bound, and it is actually attained, so it is in fact the minimum.

Comment: @dxiv I see, so the lower bound should never depend on $x$? Also, 5/2 should be 9/2.

Comment: @user2888499 Thanks for catching that, fixed now. And, right, the lower bound you get by AM-GM directly is a function of $x$ itself, and there is no guarantee that the minimum of *that* function would happen at the same point where AM-GM becomes an equality, so such a "dependent" lower bound doesn't usually help.

Answer (score 0):

This is ***not*** an answer but an illustration.

[image]
I agree with dxiv that OP found a lower bound instead of greatest lower bound. Actually, when we split an expression into 2 and then use A.M.$\geq $G.M., we can create many lower bound, which may be dependent on a variable. In order to get the greatest lower bound a constant, we need to split the expression wisely  as dxiv.

### Heading